# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions in react redux async functions

Tags: reactjs, redux, action

I am getting the above error when implementing 2 functions as below in react redux. please check.
Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. Error on async lines in the 2nd function below:-

```
async function getResourceDataMap(stationCode, event) {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    let sheetIndexMap = await readXlsxFile(file, { getSheets : true} );
    let resourceDataMap = {};

    /*
         Consider all the sheets
         */
     sheetIndexMap.map(async (sheet) => {
      let sheetName = sheet.name;

      if(isSheetNameValid(sheetName)) {
        console.log("Entered for sheetName::" + sheetName);
        let sheetRows = await readXlsxFile(file, { sheet: sheetName });
        if (sheetRows != null && sheetRows.length > 1) { // we need atleast two rows
            let headers = sheetRows[0];
            console.log("header obtained is:" +headers);

            if(isColumnNamesValid(sheetName, headers)) {
                let sheetMapList = getSheetMap(sheetRows);
                console.log("SheetMapList obtained is:" + sheetMapList);

                // STEP : Create a map of the various sheets (corresponding to each resource type)
                console.log("SheetName here is::::::::" +sheetName);
                resourceDataMap[sheetName] = {
                    headerRows: headers,
                    sheetMapList : sheetMapList
                };
                console.log("Resource data Map within :" + resourceDataMap["PRE_STAGING_AREA"]);
            }
        }
      }
    })
    return resourceDataMap;
```

}

```
export function readResourceFile(stationCode, event) {
return async dispatch => {
      const resourceDataMap = await dispatch(getResourceDataMap(stationCode, event));
      dispatch(updateResourceDataMap(resourceDataMap));
    }
```

}

Worked after Removing dispatch, but the 2 functions are parallely executing. How can I take response from one and call the other function?

Comment: why you declare `resourceDataMap = await dispatch(getResourceDataMap(...` with `dispatch`? if it is not an action suppose to get through reducer, use it normally `resourceDataMap = await getResourceDataMap(...`

Comment: Ok with removing dispatch, it is updating but the 2 functions are parallely executing, how can I take response from one function and call the other one with updated response?